# SCSS nesting, targeting a dom by its ID or class

Tags: sass, flexbox, nested, jsfiddle

I'm doing a centered nabber in a flexbox, but sometimes one item in the navbar isn't centered, the logo is at the left or a login button at the right. I'm learning SCSS nesting and my goal was to use the "align-self" property and put an item to flex-end or flex-start. But when I'm trying to target the specific element it does not work.I'm not even trying to change its flex box property, just the color in order to see if the nesting was working, but it seems like it's not the case. You can see the JSfiddle embedded below, just hit "Run the Code".

```html
<iframe width="100%" height="300" src="//jsfiddle.net/ImFilou/k8Lstyeg/22/embedded/" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" allowpaymentrequest frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't 100% clear to me so I *assume* your problem is that the final selector `& ul .special` does not allow you to change the text `home` to white.

This is just because your selector is not specific enough, change it to `& ul .special a`

Also your use of the [parent selector `&`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/style-rules/parent-selector#in-sassscript) is not necessary in all these cases, so remove it for `ul .special a`

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, thanks you it works, not to mention you assumed well. Have a nice day, thanks you a lot